# Unstack operation BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible in Big Query to perform an unstack operation such that

```
Name  Age Height   
John  27   183
Maria 32   169
```

to obtain

```
Name  attr   value 
John  Age     27
John  Height  183
Maria Age     32
Maria Height  169
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply **UNPIVOT** it.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'John' Name, 27 Age, 183 Height
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Maria', 32, 169
) UNPIVOT (value FOR attr IN (Age, Height))
```

[image]

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unpivot_operator

Answer (score 2):

Another option is less sexy but still can be useful in some scenarios

```
select Name, attr, value
from your_table, unnest([
  struct(Age as value, 'Age' as attr), 
  struct(Height, 'Height')]
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Though BigQuery provides **UNPIVOT**, still I love this approach.